# Combine the two sentence into a single sentence

Tags: grammar

I have some bills.I must pay them. how to combine this two sentence into one?

Answer (score 1):

I have some bills that must be paid.

Comment: As Reg Dwight has said, '[W]e write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer. [This] is not really a topic for a site for linguists and etymologists, and we don't want it to become a topic.' –